# Is it possible to have one product in multiple categories in Sitecore commerce 9.0.2

Tags: sitecore-commerce

I have installed sitecore commerce 9.0.2. Just wanted to know is it possible to have one product in multiple categories in Sitecore commerce 9.0.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.
Sitecore Commerce supports it OOTB.

**The Catalog service capabilities include:**

- managing and storing standardized catalogs or lists of catalogs
- managing and storing categories within catalogs
- creating and managing sellable items, including product bundles
- **associating sellable items
  to multiple catalogs, and to categories within catalogs**
- associating    sellable items from multiple catalogs to product bundles
- calculating bulk pricing for a catalog item
- managing and storing list pricing for
  a sellable item, in multiple currencies

Documentation [link](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/sitecore-experience-commerce/en/catalog-service.html)